# Mongo Aggregation pipeline update or push

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pipeline

I have a MongoDB Model which consist of array of members as obejcts.

```
const guestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  salutation: {
    type: String,
  },
  members: [membersSchema],
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});
```

Members Schema:

```
const membersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  status: {
    type: String, 
    enum: ['regular', 'helper'],
    default: 'regular',
  },
});
```

I want to achieve of doing an update in case documet with given ID exist or push to an array in case ID with document in array does not exist. I use aggregation pipeline, however I am not able to achieve pushing new document to array. Why can't I use push after else statement like this.

```
const subDocumentToUpsert = { 'name': mem.name, 'status': mem.status, '_id': ObjectId(mem.id)}
      const subDocumentNoID = { 'name': mem.name, 'status': mem.status}


await Guest.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id": req.params.id },
        [
          {
            $set: {
              members: {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $in: [subDocumentToUpsert._id, '$members._id'] },
                  then: {
                    $map: {
                      input: '$members',
                      as: 'sub_document',
                      in: {
                        $cond: {
                          if: { $eq: ['$$sub_document._id', subDocumentToUpsert._id] },
                          then: subDocumentToUpsert,
                          else: '$$sub_document',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  else: { 
                        $push: {
                          subDocumentNoID
                        }, 
                      },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
      ]);
```

What is the best way of doing so? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do as follow:

```
db.collection.update({
 _id: {
  $in: [
    1,
    2
  ]
 }
},
[
{
$set: {
  members: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $in: [
          5,
          "$members._id"
        ]
      },
      then: {
        $map: {
          input: "$members",
          as: "sub",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$sub._id",
                  5
                ]
              },
              then: {
                _id: 5,
                status: "regular_updated",
                name: "Negan_updated"
              },
              else: "$$sub"
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      else: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$members",
          [
            {
              _id: 5,
              status: "regular_upserted",
              name: "Negan_upserted"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }    
    }  
  }
 }
}    
}
],
{
 multi: true
})
```

Explained:

1. Check if _id:5 exist in the subobject and update via $map/$cond only the object that has the _id:5.
2. In case there is no _id:5 add the new object to the array with $concatArrays.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lLQHwPn656Y)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason why I wanted to push it to the array was that It should be a new object which does have its own ID. ID should be created after its inicialization according to memberSchema. I want to have it as "mongo objectID". With concat it is only and object without ID. Is there a way to create it like I want?

Comment: @jirka8 :  You can autogenerate the ObjectId() before insertion in mongoose as follow:  _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

Comment: Also there is no point to check if specific _id exists in array when you will want to insert other _id  ...

Comment: Great, it looks that my problem is solved by adding new ObjectId to a new array element.